# Error message: The 'feature_names' parameter of plot_tree must be an instance of 'list' or None

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7.5))
plot_tree(clf_dt, filled= True, `rounded=True, class_names = ["No HD","Yes HD"], feature_names=X_encoded.columns)
```

I am new to machine learning and python. Trying to plot a classification tree for the heart disease  data from the UCI repository. After performing on-hot encoding for the categorical variables and storing it in X_encoded, when I try to plot the tree, it is giving me this error message:

```
InvalidParameterError: The 'feature_names' parameter of plot_tree must be an instance of 'list' or None. Got Index(['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'restbp', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 'thalach',
       'exang', 'oldpeak', 'slope', 'ca', 'thal'],
      dtype='object') instead.
```

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. As shown in this [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW1ZF.png), `feature_names=df.columns` works without issue. Note the versions in the screen shot. I'm voting to close this issue as not reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an Index object rather than a list. Change to the following and you will have a list that you need.

```
feature_names=X_encoded.columns.tolist()
```

Comment: Passing a `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` to `feature_names=` works without issue in scikit-learn version 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this parameter like this way

```
feature_names = X_encoded.feature_names[:]
```

fill index according to your need